# `geom_density_ridges()` requires the following missing aesthetics: y (grouping function unresponsive)

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes, group

I have the current dataset structure:

```
head(subset)

batch antigen expression_value dataset
1     5    CD57        1.7917310  before
2     5    CD57        1.2932388  before
3     5    CD57        0.3179733  before
4     5    CD57        0.3761151  before
5     5    CD57        0.6780204  before
6     5    CD57        0.6050466  before
```

in which

batch can be a number between 1-7 (factor w/ 7 levels)
antigen can be either of 13 markers (e.g. CD4, Cd8) (factor w/ 13 levels)
expression_value is a number (some are negative)
datset can either be before or after (factor w/ 2 levels)

if I run this code I get the following picture:

```
ggplot(subset,
aes(x = expression_value,
y = antigen))+
geom_density_ridges(alpha = 0.5)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgBSn.png)

Now, there is a density plot for the whole datsaet, but I want to change each individual plot to the density plots per batch (so I want to have 7 overlaying density graphs but still only 13 rows. As I want to compare the densities between the batches.
I tried this code:

```
ggplot(subset,
aes(x = expression_value,
y = antigen,
group = batch))+
geom_density_ridges(alpha = 0.5)
```

however, this is the error and output:

```
Picking joint bandwidth of 0.0423
Error in `geom_density_ridges()`:
! Problem while setting up geom.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `compute_geom_1()`:
! `geom_density_ridges()` requires the following missing aesthetics: y
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: y
ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in the data.
ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a
factor?
```

```
rlang::last_error()
\<error/rlang_error\>
Error in `geom_density_ridges()`:
! Problem while setting up geom.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `compute_geom_1()`:
! `geom_density_ridges()` requires the following missing aesthetics: y
-

Backtrace:

1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
3. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
4. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
5. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers\[\[i\]\], d = data\[\[i\]\])
6. l$compute_geom_1(d)
7. ggplot2 (local) compute_geom_1(..., self = self)
```

I tried to change everything from factor to character and back but I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Does someone else see?

In the end I want a plot with all the markers on the y axis, the expression value on the x-axis, and then for each marker a before/after under each other. So I can compare all the batches before and after with each other.

Let me know!

```
session_info()
─ Session info ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
setting  value
version  R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
os       Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.7 (Ootpa)
system   x86_64, linux-gnu
ui       RStudio
language (EN)
collate  en_US.UTF-8
ctype    en_US.UTF-8
tz       Europe/Amsterdam
date     2023-04-25
rstudio  2022.07.2+576 Spotted Wakerobin (server)
pandoc   2.18 @ /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/ (via rmarkdown)

─ Packages ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
package                \* version   date (UTC) lib source
abind                    1.4-5     2016-07-21 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
AnnotationDbi            1.60.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
AnnotationHub          \* 3.6.0     2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
askpass                  1.1       2019-01-13 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
assertthat               0.2.1     2019-03-21 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
backports                1.4.1     2021-12-13 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
beachmat                 2.14.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
beeswarm                 0.4.0     2021-06-01 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
Biobase                \* 2.58.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
BiocFileCache          \* 2.6.0     2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
BiocGenerics           \* 0.44.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
BiocManager            \* 1.30.20   2023-02-24 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
BiocNeighbors            1.16.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
BiocParallel           \* 1.32.4    2022-12-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
BiocSingular             1.14.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
BiocStyle              \* 2.26.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
BiocVersion              3.16.0    2022-04-26 \[1\] Bioconductor
Biostrings               2.66.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
bit                      4.0.5     2022-11-15 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
bit64                    4.0.5     2020-08-30 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
bitops                   1.0-7     2021-04-24 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
blob                     1.2.3     2022-04-10 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
boot                     1.3-28.1  2022-11-22 \[2\] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
broom                    1.0.2     2022-12-15 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
cachem                   1.0.6     2021-08-19 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
Cairo                    1.6-0     2022-07-05 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
callr                    3.7.3     2022-11-02 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
car                      3.1-1     2022-10-19 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
carData                  3.0-5     2022-01-06 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
CATALYST               \* 1.22.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
cellranger               1.1.0     2016-07-27 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
changepoint              2.2.4     2022-11-03 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
checkmate                2.1.0     2022-04-21 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
circlize                 0.4.15    2022-05-10 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
cli                      3.6.0     2023-01-09 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
clue                     0.3-64    2023-01-31 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
cluster                  2.1.4     2022-08-22 \[2\] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
codetools                0.2-19    2023-02-01 \[2\] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
colorRamps               2.3.1     2022-05-02 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
colorspace               2.1-0     2023-01-23 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
ComplexHeatmap           2.14.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
ConsensusClusterPlus   \* 1.62.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
corpcor                  1.6.10    2021-09-16 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
cowplot                \* 1.1.1     2020-12-30 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
crayon                   1.5.2     2022-09-29 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
curl                     5.0.0     2023-01-12 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
cytolib                  2.10.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
CytoNorm               \* 0.0.10    2023-02-13 \[1\] Github (saeyslab/CytoNorm@166f9ff)
data.table               1.14.8    2023-02-17 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
DBI                      1.1.3     2022-06-18 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
dbplyr                 \* 2.2.1     2022-06-27 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
DelayedArray           \* 0.24.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
DelayedMatrixStats       1.20.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
deldir                   1.0-6     2021-10-23 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
DEoptimR                 1.0-11    2022-04-03 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
deSolve                  1.34      2022-10-22 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
devtools               \* 2.4.5     2022-10-11 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
diffcyt                \* 1.18.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
digest                 \* 0.6.31    2022-12-11 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
doParallel               1.0.17    2022-02-07 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
dplyr                  \* 1.0.10    2022-09-01 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
drc                      3.0-1     2016-08-30 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
dunn.test              \* 1.3.5     2017-10-27 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
edgeR                    3.40.1    2022-12-14 \[1\] Bioconductor
ellipsis                 0.3.2     2021-04-29 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
evaluate                 0.20      2023-01-17 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
ExperimentHub          \* 2.6.0     2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
fansi                    1.0.4     2023-01-22 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
farver                   2.1.1     2022-07-06 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
fastmap                  1.1.1     2023-02-24 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
fda                      6.0.5     2022-07-04 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
fds                      1.8       2018-10-31 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
filelock                 1.0.2     2018-10-05 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
flowAI                 \* 1.28.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
flowClust                3.36.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
flowCore               \* 2.10.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
FlowSOM                \* 2.6.0     2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
flowStats              \* 4.10.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
flowViz                \* 1.62.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
flowWorkspace            4.10.1    2022-12-29 \[1\] Bioconductor
forcats                \* 1.0.0     2023-01-29 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
foreach                  1.5.2     2022-02-02 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
fs                       1.6.1     2023-02-06 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
gargle                   1.2.1     2022-09-08 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
generics                 0.1.3     2022-07-05 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
GenomeInfoDb           \* 1.34.9    2023-02-02 \[1\] Bioconductor
GenomeInfoDbData         1.2.9     2022-11-22 \[1\] Bioconductor
GenomicRanges          \* 1.50.2    2022-12-16 \[1\] Bioconductor
GetoptLong               1.0.5     2020-12-15 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
ggbeeswarm               0.7.1     2022-12-16 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
ggforce                  0.4.1     2022-10-04 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
ggnewscale               0.4.8     2022-10-06 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
ggplot2                \* 3.4.0     2022-11-04 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
ggpubr                 \* 0.5.0     2022-11-16 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
ggrepel                  0.9.2     2022-11-06 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
ggridges               \* 0.5.4     2022-09-26 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
ggsignif                 0.6.4     2022-10-13 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
GlobalOptions            0.1.2     2020-06-10 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
glue                     1.6.2     2022-02-24 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
googledrive              2.0.0     2021-07-08 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
googlesheets4            1.0.1     2022-08-13 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
graph                    1.76.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
gridExtra              \* 2.3       2017-09-09 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
gtable                   0.3.1     2022-09-01 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
gtools                   3.9.4     2022-11-27 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
haven                    2.5.1     2022-08-22 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
hdrcde                   3.4       2021-01-18 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
hexbin                   1.28.2    2021-01-08 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
hms                      1.1.2     2022-08-19 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
htmltools                0.5.4     2022-12-07 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
htmlwidgets              1.6.1     2023-01-07 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
httpuv                   1.6.7     2022-12-14 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
httr                     1.4.4     2022-08-17 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
IDPmisc                  1.1.20    2020-01-21 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
igraph                 \* 1.3.5     2022-09-22 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
interactiveDisplayBase   1.36.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
interp                   1.1-3     2022-07-13 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
IRanges                \* 2.32.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
irlba                    2.3.5.1   2022-10-03 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
iterators                1.0.14    2022-02-05 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
jpeg                     0.1-10    2022-11-29 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
jsonlite                 1.8.4     2022-12-06 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
KEGGREST                 1.38.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
KernSmooth               2.23-20   2021-05-03 \[2\] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
knitr                  \* 1.41      2022-11-18 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
ks                       1.14.0    2022-11-24 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
labeling                 0.4.2     2020-10-20 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
later                    1.3.0     2021-08-18 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
lattice                \* 0.20-45   2021-09-22 \[2\] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
latticeExtra             0.6-30    2022-07-04 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
lifecycle                1.0.3     2022-10-07 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
limma                  \* 3.54.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
lme4                     1.1-31    2022-11-01 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
locfit                   1.5-9.7   2023-01-02 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
lubridate                1.9.0     2022-11-06 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
magick                   2.7.3     2021-08-18 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
magrittr                 2.0.3     2022-03-30 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
MASS                     7.3-58.2  2023-01-23 \[2\] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
Matrix                 \* 1.5-3     2022-11-11 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
MatrixGenerics         \* 1.10.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
matrixStats            \* 0.63.0    2022-11-18 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
mclust                   6.0.0     2022-10-31 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
memoise                  2.0.1     2021-11-26 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
metR                   \* 0.13.0    2022-10-06 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
mime                     0.12      2021-09-28 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
miniUI                   0.1.1.1   2018-05-18 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
minqa                    1.2.5     2022-10-19 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
mnormt                   2.1.1     2022-09-26 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
modelr                   0.1.10    2022-11-11 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
multcomp                 1.4-20    2022-08-07 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
munsell                  0.5.0     2018-06-12 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
mvtnorm                  1.1-3     2021-10-08 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
ncdfFlow                 2.44.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
nlme                     3.1-162   2023-01-31 \[2\] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
nloptr                   2.0.3     2022-05-26 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
nnls                     1.4       2012-03-19 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
openCyto               \* 2.10.1    2022-12-02 \[1\] Bioconductor
openssl                  2.0.5     2022-12-06 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
pcaPP                    2.0-3     2022-10-24 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
pdftools               \* 3.3.2     2022-10-16 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
PeacoQC                \* 1.8.0     2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
pheatmap               \* 1.0.12    2019-01-04 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
pillar                   1.8.1     2022-08-19 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
pkgbuild                 1.4.0     2022-11-27 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
pkgconfig                2.0.3     2019-09-22 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
pkgload                  1.3.2     2022-11-16 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
plotrix                  3.8-2     2021-09-08 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
plyr                     1.8.8     2022-11-11 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
png                      0.1-8     2022-11-29 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
polyclip                 1.10-4    2022-10-20 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
pracma                   2.4.2     2022-09-22 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
premessa               \* 0.3.4     2023-02-24 \[1\] Github (ParkerICI/premessa@68b42bb)
prettyunits              1.1.1     2020-01-24 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
processx                 3.8.0     2022-10-26 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
profvis                  0.3.7     2020-11-02 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
promises                 1.2.0.1   2021-02-11 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
ps                       1.7.2     2022-10-26 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
purrr                  \* 1.0.1     2023-01-10 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
qpdf                     1.3.0     2022-10-07 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
R6                       2.5.1     2021-08-19 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
rainbow                  3.7       2022-10-09 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
RANN                   \* 2.6.1     2019-01-08 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
rappdirs                 0.3.3     2021-01-31 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
RBGL                     1.74.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
RColorBrewer           \* 1.1-3     2022-04-03 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
Rcpp                   \* 1.0.10    2023-01-22 \[2\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
RCurl                    1.98-1.9  2022-10-03 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
readr                  \* 2.1.3     2022-10-01 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
readxl                 \* 1.4.1     2022-08-17 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
remotes                  2.4.2     2021-11-30 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
reprex                   2.0.2     2022-08-17 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
reshape2               \* 1.4.4     2020-04-09 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
reticulate               1.27      2023-01-07 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
Rgraphviz                2.42.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
rJava                    1.0-6     2021-12-10 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
rjson                    0.2.21    2022-01-09 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
rlang                    1.0.6     2022-09-24 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
rmarkdown                2.19      2022-12-15 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
robustbase               0.95-0    2022-04-02 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
RProtoBufLib             2.10.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
rrcov                    1.7-2     2022-10-24 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
RSpectra                 0.16-1    2022-04-24 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
RSQLite                  2.2.19    2022-11-24 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
rstatix                  0.7.1     2022-11-09 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
rstudioapi               0.14      2022-08-22 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
rsvd                     1.0.5     2021-04-16 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
Rtsne                  \* 0.16      2022-04-17 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
rvest                    1.0.3     2022-08-19 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
S4Vectors              \* 0.36.1    2022-12-05 \[1\] Bioconductor
sandwich                 3.0-2     2022-06-15 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
ScaledMatrix             1.6.0     2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
scales                   1.2.1     2022-08-20 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
scater                   1.26.1    2022-11-13 \[1\] Bioconductor
scuttle                  1.8.2     2022-12-07 \[1\] Bioconductor
sessioninfo              1.2.2     2021-12-06 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
shape                    1.4.6     2021-05-19 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
shiny                    1.7.4     2022-12-15 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
SingleCellExperiment   \* 1.20.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
sparseMatrixStats        1.10.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
Spectre                \* 1.0.0     2022-11-22 \[1\] Github (immunedynamics/spectre@3d0c002)
stringi                  1.7.12    2023-01-11 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
stringr                \* 1.5.0     2022-12-02 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
SummarizedExperiment   \* 1.28.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
survival                 3.5-3     2023-02-12 \[2\] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
TH.data                  1.1-1     2022-04-26 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
tibble                 \* 3.1.8     2022-07-22 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
tidyr                  \* 1.2.1     2022-09-08 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
tidyselect               1.2.0     2022-10-10 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
tidyverse              \* 1.3.2     2022-07-18 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
timechange               0.2.0     2023-01-11 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
tweenr                   2.0.2     2022-09-06 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
tzdb                     0.3.0     2022-03-28 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
umap                   \* 0.2.9.0   2022-08-25 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
urlchecker               1.0.1     2021-11-30 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
usethis                \* 2.1.6     2022-05-25 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
utf8                     1.2.2     2021-07-24 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
vctrs                    0.5.1     2022-11-16 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
vipor                    0.4.5     2017-03-22 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
viridis                  0.6.2     2021-10-13 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
viridisLite              0.4.1     2022-08-22 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
withr                    2.5.0     2022-03-03 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
xfun                     0.36      2022-12-21 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
xlsx                   \* 0.6.5     2020-11-10 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
xlsxjars                 0.6.1     2014-08-22 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
XML                      3.99-0.13 2022-12-04 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
xml2                     1.3.3     2021-11-30 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
xtable                   1.8-4     2019-04-21 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
XVector                  0.38.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
yaml                     2.3.6     2022-10-18 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
zlibbioc                 1.44.0    2022-11-01 \[1\] Bioconductor
zoo                      1.8-11    2022-09-17 \[1\] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the `geom_density_ridges()` function requires the `y` aesthetic to be defined, which is not currently defined in your code. This is because the `y` aesthetic is being used to group the data by batch, but the y aesthetic is also needed to plot the density ridges.

Try this:

```
    ggplot(subset,
       aes(x = expression_value,
           y = antigen,
           fill = batch))+
  geom_density_ridges(alpha = 0.5)+
  facet_wrap(~batch, ncol = 1)
```

we are using the `fill` aesthetic to group the data by `batch` for the density plot, and we are using the `facet_wrap()` function to create separate plots for each `batch`. The `ncol = 1` argument specifies that each plot should have one column.